# How do I bind a method delegate as the value of a comboBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a WinForms ComboBox that will allow the user to select which type of correlation calculation to perform.

I want to bind the method delegate to the value of the ComboBox item.  Currently I am using a switch statement that cases off of the text of the ComboBox item to set the appropriate method.

I would like to bind the methods directly to the Value of the ComboBox items like this...

```
public class CorrelationItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Func<double?[],double?[],double> Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}

var ci = new CorrelationItem();
ci.Text = "Absolute Difference Calculation";
ci.Value = engine.AbsoluteValueDifferenceCalculation;

ddlCorrelationMethods.ValueMember = "Value";
ddlCorrelationMethods.DisplayMember = "Text";
ddlCorrelationMethods.Items.Add(ci);
ddlCorrelationMethods.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

When I do this, the ddlCorrelationMethods.SelectedValue is null.

Comment: `ddlCorrelationMethods.DataSource = new[] { ci };`

Comment: How is `cbCalcTypes` related to `ddlCorrelationMethods`?  Are you setting the item `ci` into `ddlCorrelationMethods` but checking a different ComboBox?

Comment: @SeanSkelly They are the same control, but cbCalcTypes was the original name that was changed and I forgot to update the text before I posted.

Comment: @Jimi That works as expected, thank you.  

Now, why does creating a new array of ci and setting that as the data source for the control work when adding ci as an item does not?

Comment: Because adding an item to the Items collection just adds an object to the underlying `ObjectCollection` (this object derives from `IList`). Setting the DataSource, wires the Data object, also setting the specified `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` values, so `SelectedValue`, which is returned by the internal DataManager, will actually have a value. `new[] { ci }` because the `DataSource` object requires a collection (that implements `IList` or `IListSource`).